# Symfony / EasyAdmin : CollectionType display key/value

Tags: arrays, json, forms, symfony, easyadmin

I store json in a field

```
{
    'key': {
        'value': 42,
        'field': 'IntegerField'
    },
    'key2': {
        'value': 'myValue',
        'field': 'TextField'
    },
}
```

It's a Collection for Symfony

In EasyAdmin, in new/edit page I want to display a form from this json => associative array:

`Key : <input>value</input>`

But I don't know how to overide the block `{% block collection_entry_row %}`

```php
class MyEntityCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return MyEntity::class;
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): array
    {
        return [
            ...parent::configureFields($pageName),
            TextField::new('public'),
            CollectionField::new('ressources'), <-- override the render in easyadmin 
        ];
    }

    /...

}
```

I try to create custom field, custom type but I don't know to render the template in EasyAdmin